# javascript postmessage doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, web, frontend

i have 2 sites, and i want to use javascript`postMessage` between them.
on my main site i write the following code in an emty html file :

```
<html>

<script>

window.addEventListener("message",listener_,false);
function listener_(event) {
    console.log('ok!');
    <html>

<script>

window.addEventListener("message",listener_,false);
function listener_(event) {
    console.log('ok!');
    //console.log(event);
    //console.log(event.data);

}

</script>

</html>
```

and in other site that i want to call the postmessage from the i write the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
    testfunction();
    };
function testfunction(){


    var childWin = window.open("http://my-main-site.com/indexjava2.html","child");
    childWin = postMessage('message','*');


    console.log(TipaltiIframeInfo.height);


}

</script>
```

but it doesn't work after a  lot of tries. i mean 
console.log('ok!'); or console.log(event); console.log(event.data);

doesn't trigger on console of main site,

what to do? 
thanks

Comment: In the first code block there is an unnecesarry `<script>` tag and there is a `<html>` tag in script tag. Fix those first.

Comment: just to get the obvious out of the way.. your posted code shows two listener callbacks with an opening `<script>` tag between them.  That script tag will cause an error and neither work.  Is this just a typo while posting here, or is this what you really have on your page?

Comment: Hopefully my answer is comprehensive enough that you can get it working now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside from the fact that you've got a `<script>` and an `<html>` tag in the middle of your code for the receiving page and you're defining and adding the event listener twice, you're also not use `postMessage` correctly. Instead of this:

```
childWin = postMessage('message', '*');
```

...it should be this:

```
childWin.postMessage('message', '*');
```

If you want to learn more about `postMessage`, [read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

The other issue is that the message won't be received by the newly-opened page unless the page is opened before the message is sent. You're trying to send the message immediately after opening the new page, and the message is reaching the new page before the event listener is added. You could get around this with a `setTimeout`, but if the new page takes longer to load then this might also be unreliable.

```
// This is what NOT to do:
setTimeout(function() {
    childWin.postMessage('message', '*');
}, 1000);
```

Instead, the better way is for the child page to tell the parent page when it's loaded. Then the parent and child can communicate reliably.

---

Here is the full corrected code, sending page first:

```
<script>
    var childWin;

    window.addEventListener('message', messageListener, false);

    function messageListener(event) {
        if(event.data == 'ready') {
            childWin.postMessage('hello second page', '*');
        }
    }

    window.onload = function() {
        childWin = window.open('http://my-main-site.com/indexjava2.htm', 'child');
    };
</script>
```

And the receiving page:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('message', messageListener, false);

    function messageListener(event) {
        console.log(event.data);
    }

    window.opener.postMessage('ready','*');
</script>
```

Comment: @anon No worries, I like to try to ensure my answers don't miss out on anything :) Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: @anon I just realised I should have made it send the "ready" message _after_ the event listener was added on the receiving page to be genuinely reliable. I've edited my post with the change. If you go to the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44770585/revisions) of my post you'll be able to see the change, but all I did was move the `window.opener.postMessage('ready','*');` line to the end of the script for the receiving page.

Comment: thanks, yes i had problem with that , i used the firs method with setting setTimeout of 5000. thans alot